# Using variable PivotTable and PivotField names

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to get out of "Name Hard Coding" and moving into "Variable Coding" so I can use my code in other pivots regardless of which field names are in my Data Source. I wonder what's wrong in my sample code below...

I get the following error:
Run-Time Error '1004':
Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

I am using "Excel Binary Workbook (*.xlsb) from Microsoft Office 2013

For instance:

Name Hard Coding:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Item")
```

This one works like beauty!

Variable Coding:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtTable).PivotFields(pvtField)
```

This one does not work!

Sample Code:

```
Sub VariablePivotName_and_PivotField()

Dim pvtTable As PivotTable, pvtField As PivotField

For Each pvtTable In ActiveSheet.PivotTables

    For Each pvtField In pvtTable.PivotFields

'        MsgBox pvtTable.Name

'        MsgBox pvtField.Name

'        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields("Item")               '''' This one works like beauty!

        With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtTable).PivotFields(pvtField)                    ''''This one does not work!

            .Orientation = xlRowField       'Could be any other thing I want to change

            .LayoutForm = xlTabular         'Could be any other thing I want to change

        End With

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Try just using variables for table OR field rather than both to narrow down your problem. Also can you put all of your code into a code block markdown to improve the readability of this question please.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on the code blocks @Caltor. I could not figure it out originally so desperation took hold of me to hit post :)

Comment: @Luuklag kindly came to rescue here so thanks to him for making it better!

Comment: Nice work @Luuklag. I would have edited it myself but it popped into my review queue without an edit option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that you are trying to use the variables pvtTable and pvtField as Strings, not as the object types that they are.

The lines:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtTable).PivotFields(pvtField)                    
    .Orientation = xlRowField
```

Are trying to get the PivotTable with the name as a string, pvtTable and then get the PivotField with the name as a string, pvtField, but unfortunately neither of these variables are strings.

A line that would work is:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvtTable.Name).PivotFields( pvtField.Name)                    
    .Orientation = xlRowField
End With
```

because pvtTable.Name is a property of the pivottable that is a string.  Similarly pvtField.Name is a property of the pivotField that is a string.

It would be easier to just use the code:

```
With pvtField
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .LayoutForm = xlTabular
End With
```

As this will act on the fields of the PivotField object.

Comment: Thanks for the response @OpiesDad, worked perfectly well. You saved my day! :)